# Issue with social login plugin of magento

Tags: magento, plugins

I have a website where I have installed a **plugin Magegaint Social Login.**

While registering through Google or Facebook, its registering. I checked in the admin panel, registration is confirmed.

But when I try to sign in through next time by Google, error message shows that account not activated.

Also mail is not going to the customer who has newly registered.

I have attached the picture below.

I will be glad to know some solutions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIel1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try it after disabled customer Activation module. B'coz this module also overwrite same function and method for customers.

```
Go To app/etc/modules/module_name.xml
```